# US, legal producing pornography, illegal prostitution

Tags: criminal-law

If prostitution is illegal in the US, but production of pornography legal, couldn't johns/punters just offer prostitutes money for filming a pornographic movie instead of money in exchange of sex?

Answer (score 2):

At least in the US, trying to evade one law (prostitution) by complying with another set of laws (porn film production) gets very complicated, very quickly and is a simply unrealistic endeavor. Laws are written with loopholes in mind, and even if there was an obvious loophole as you imagine, it could be closed rather quickly.

To be more specific, any porn film production of any size is very heavily regulated at the state and federal level, and your legal liability in shooting even a simple, one off film without permits, insurance, taxes, etc., is much greater than the relatively simple simple prostitute/john situation. Google "porn film regulations" to get an idea of the differences.

Comment: What is an example of a federal regulation on the porn industry?

Comment: @user6726 Federal requirements that you have made adequate verification of all actors's ages and have adequate records thereof?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Actually its State, not Federal requirements... specifically California because most porn is produced there.   18 years of age is the age of consent in California and is rather high for the U.S.  More states have the age at 16 years old than not.   If you shoot in one state it's no business of the Feds what the actor's ages are.

Comment: While it's illegal to pay people to have sex, it's not illegal to pay for the rights to film two people having sex.   Thus the loophole follows:  Alice and Bob are actors in a porno produced by Chuck.   If Chuck gives Alice and Bob money to have sex it's prostitution.   If Alice and Bob agree to have sex and Chuck wants to offer them money to film  that act, then it's legal porn.  Who comes up with the idea that Bob and Alice are gonna get it on is moot, but Chuck is buying the right to film and edit it, but not paying either for the sex.   Distinction without a difference, but it works.

Comment: @hsmv [Nope, it's federal](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2257).  You'll note I never mentioned a specific age requirement.  But verifying the ages and maintaining records is a federal requirement.

Comment: @hsmv And if you check the flagged duplicate you'll see you can't just transition from prostitution to constitutionally protected (via free speech) porn that easily (short of a jury randomly favoring you).  The number of things you must comply with and be able to convince a jury of are so numerous and difficult that your attempts to pretend your prostitution isn't porn is going to fail unless it was actually a legitimate porno.

Comment: And the age requirement of 18 is also required federally, though it's harder for me to pin down by what.  The uniform labeling requirements of the Child Protection and Obscenity Enforcement Act of 1988, which is basically in the link above, seems to be cited as why, though I can't find any plainly obvious language asserting this.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy 18 U.S. Code § 2251 is fairly clear that you can't have a minor as a porn actor, I think.